# Change subview layer position

Tags: xcode, uiview, layer, zposition

Good evening,

I have been trying to figure out how to fade a screen when I press a button in order to give a subview a more distinct appearance. I have researched zPositions and I thought that implementing this feature within my code would help. When I run my code, the entire screen fades. I would like there to be a circle progress ring that shows up, while the background is faded.  I will show a picture and my code. Thank you in advance.

[image: The circle ring, I would like to be abover the faded screen.]

```
 @objc func handlePost() {
    let center = view.center
    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    blackScreen=UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    blackScreen.backgroundColor=UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.8)
    blackScreen.isHidden=true
    self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(blackScreen)
    blackScreen.layer.zPosition=50
    blackScreen.isHidden=false
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    // The zPosition is supposed to bring this layer to the front. 
    trackLayer.zPosition = 100
    shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = GREEN_Theme.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    // The zPosition is supposed to bring this layer to the front. 
    shapeLayer.zPosition = 100
    let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    basicAnimation.toValue = 1
    basicAnimation.duration = 2
    basicAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "dataSearch")
    shapeLayer.removeAnimation(forKey: "finished")
    view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

}

Comment: This just a duplicate of your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53386470/fade-out-a-uiview-after-pressing-a-button. Don’t do that.

Comment: @matt this is not a duplicate. They are two different questions. The first question was asking how to fade the screen, this question is asking how to bring a layer above the fade. Thank you for you concern though!

Comment: @matt I did see how they go hand in hand, so I deleted the previous post and decided to keep this one. Because it does answer the previous question, and now it is asking a new one

Comment: @matt I did that by using zPosition, but when I run the app it still shows behind. I’ve cleaned build history and re ran it and it still shows this way.

Answer (score 1):

Again after spending hours with my code, I managed to figure out my own answer.
before I had

```
     self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(blackScreen)
  // (faded screen)
```

I simply needed to add

```
    self.view.addSubview(blackScreen)
```

to turn it into a layer that way I could manipulate it with my zPosition.